# XY amchart with text on yAxis not wok

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, amcharts

I am trying to draw **Reversed Value Axis** of Amchart.

It prints error "Data fields for series "Currency" are not properly defined".

I think there is some problem with text-base y axis.

Here is my code:

```js
    
    function XYChart() {
      let myData = [
        {
          year: "2008",
          label: "COLOCATION",
        },
        // other objects
      ];
      useEffect(() => {
        am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
        var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
        chart.data = myData;
        var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
        xAxis.dataFields.category = "year";
        xAxis.renderer.opposite = false;

        var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
        yAxis.dataFields.category = "label";
        yAxis.renderer.inversed = false;
        yAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
        yAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
    
        var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series1.dataFields.valueY = "label";
        series1.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
        series1.name = "Currency";
        series1.strokeWidth = 3;
        series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
        series1.tooltipText = "{name} in {categoryX}: {valueY}";
        series1.legendSettings.valueText = "{valueY}";
        series1.visible = false;
    
        chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
        chart.cursor.behavior = "zoomY";
    
        chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
      });
    
      return (
          <div id="XYChartDiv"></div>
      );
    }
    
    export default XYChart;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dual category axes, you need to set your series dataFields to `categoryX` and `categoryY` - your code is using `valueY`, which only applies to value axes.